# How to obtain the amount of bits of a BigInt?

Tags: javascript, biginteger

There are no `bitLength()` method documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) or [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi)... How to check the number of bits of a native BigInt value?

**I am looking for a  "direct way", by  some internal information**... Or anything faster tham convert always `x.toString(2)`.

---

### notes

- Not ideal, but a intermediary  workaround (seems faster tham `toString()`) is to use [this mathematical formula based on *log2(x)*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416817/70274)... Adapted to BigInt.
- [This lib](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/master/BigInteger.js)  developed a specific `integerLogarithm(value, base)` to calculate the log2... and implement a `bitLength()` method (without `Math.floor()` hum...), but with a lot of dependencies, it is an elephant...

Comment: Probably `bigIntVal.toString(2).length`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev yes, I using it as workaround. Lost performance converting. Looking for a direct way.

Comment: I don't know much how BigInt is implemented in Javascript (I once wrote [my own for Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html)), but does the following link help? ISTM it provides ways to obtain the BigInt as array. Then its length and top value can be used to calculate what Java calls the bitLength(): https://tc39.github.io/proposal-bigint/#sec-typedarrays-and-dataview

Comment: Hi @RudyVelthuis, make sense... The way to access the internal array or count blocks, etc. is (seems) by WebAssembly.  It seems that they are developing an interface for BigInt, such as formal comments [at chromestatus](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5648655109324800) and [at WebAssembly/proposals](https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals/issues/7).

Answer (score 7):

Note: below measurements were taken in V8 (Chromium), should extend to other engines to confirm and post links to benchmarks.

Note 2: all these functions assume the argument is nonnegative, and may crash / loop / return invalid results otherwise.

### simple version

```js
return x.toString(2).length
```

as pointed out in the comments, even if it feels hacky to use toString(), it's unlikely there's an asymptotically faster way (because formatting a base 2 string is efficient and happens natively). it's O(n) with the number of bits of the bigint. other than that it's short and readable, so it's ideal for most uses.

### better version

```js
const i = (x.toString(16).length - 1) * 4
return i + 32 - Math.clz32(Number(x >> BigInt(i)))
```

this still uses the toString() approach, but it uses base 16 instead of base 2, meaning the temporary string that is produced is 4x shorter. formatting base 16 is also efficient, no real base change required, so still O(n).

the gains of using this are marginal for small bigints (+10% for 32 bits) but for big ones (such as messages or cryptography coefficients, meaning 512 / 1024 / 2048 / 4096) it's 2.5 to 4 times faster and puts less pressure on the GC as it only allocates a 2x long string. it's ideal for hot code and non-small integers.

### "you may be overthinking this" version

there's fortunately a more performant way that does not involve toString() and instead relies on pre-allocated integers of different sizes that are successively compared to the target to get an upper bound for its size, in ceil(log2(n)) steps.

once the upper bound is established, the exact size is determined by bisection:

```js
// find upper bound
let k = 0
while (true) {
    if (testersN === k) {
        testersCoeff.push(32 << testersN)
        testersBigCoeff.push(BigInt(testersCoeff[testersN]))
        testers.push(1n << testersBigCoeff[testersN])
        testersN++
    }
    if (x < testers[k]) break
    k++
}

if (!k)
    return 32 - Math.clz32(Number(x))

// determine length by bisection
k--
let i = testersCoeff[k]
let a = x >> testersBigCoeff[k]
while (k--) {
    let b = a >> testersBigCoeff[k]
    if (b)
        (i += testersCoeff[k], a = b)
}

return i + 32 - Math.clz32(Number(a))
```

this code uses the following global variables to store cached state:

```js
const testersCoeff = []
const testersBigCoeff = []
const testers = []
let testersN = 0
```

in my [tests](https://jsbench.me/eiljpnutte/1), compared with the previous version, this is 2x faster for 512 bits, 7x faster for 4096 bits. it allocates at most 1x the size of the target integer, albeit in multiple integers.

### ideal version

with proper native support, this would essentially be a O(1) operation (since the engine needs to know the length of the buffer used to store the bigint).

as for now, the best thing we can hope for is O(n) since there's no way to probe for the size of a bigint (i.e. ask if size is smaller or larger than a certain n) that does not involve an allocation proportional to n in the worst case.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hacky (but simple) way, convert it to a string:

```
num.toString(2).length;
```

---

```js
const x = 324298349892398423892439832498423989842394839842398432243234243942738742378942379824739879842379437942379423792437742397942379824379842397824312n;

console.log(x.toString(2));

const bits = x.toString(2).length;

console.log(bits);
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, it is correct (!) but sorry, it was obvious and I forgot to tell you that I'm not interested in this workaround. I edited the question.

Comment: Do not down-vote this answer, it's currently the most performant way of doing it (sadly).

Comment: @JoakimL.Christiansen and it still is \*deep sigh\*